# Using a test runner to test functions that manipulate the DOM

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, test-runner

I found out about end-to-end test runners for web applications quite recently. They basically replicate a user scenario from start to finish by literally running a web browser. There are for example NightwatchJS and TetsCafé.

There are also unit test runners like Mocha, Jasmine, AVA, Jest, QUnit. If I understand correctly they allow to test units of code like functions by comparing the returned value with the known result.

If I'm building a web application that involves handling document objects, i.e. appending and removing elements or changing their positions. Can I do this with the above five unit test runners? To me end-to-end tests runners seem to be more costly: I can't afford to run them as often as unit tests because they simply take more time.

So my question is, how can I test functions that interact with the DOM? I've found [this page](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-jquery.html) on Jest's wiki that explains how to test JQuery code. But I don't know how to test my own functions (no jQuery involved).

For example, I have a function that appends a new `div` to the `body` of the document and returns the newly created `div` element.

```
let add = function() {

  let div = createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<div class="newElement">Hello World</div>';

  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(div)
  return div

}
```

How can I test that indeed:

- `add()` returns an instance of `HTMLElement` and
- a `div` element with the class name `newElement` exists in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution testing some code. I didn't think it would work with Jest out of the box. We can actually access the DOM with `document`!

Here are the files:

**add.js:**

```
let add = function() {

    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<div class="newElement">Hello World</div>';

    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(div)
    return div
}

module.exports = add;
```

**add.test.js:**

```
const add = require('./add');

test('add() returns a HTML element', () => {

    expect(add()).toBeInstanceOf(HTMLElement)

})


it('a() creates a div with class name newElement', () => {

    add()
    let textContent = document.querySelector('.newElement').textContent
    expect(textContent).toBe('Hello World')

})
```

Typing in the command line `npm jest`, it returns:

[image]

Does somebody know why this works? Is JestJS creating an empty document to test?

Answer (score 1):

Jest uses `jsdom` as the default test environment, so the usual browser globals are accessible out of the box.

Please see https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string